# Sanitarium vs. Sanatorium

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, etymology, differences

Is there a difference between sanitarium and sanatorium? A search over the net brings some pages which say that there's not much difference. For example, [this article](https://healthfully.com/difference-between-sanatorium-sanitarium-8766941.html) says there is one difference but it does not seem like a reasonable difference to me. So, is there really a difference between the two and which one is used in the modern world?

Comment: It would be a good idea to  edit and include what that cited difference is. At the very least state the name of the source because very often links "rot" and that information is forever lost.

Comment: When I was growing up, 70 years ago, the usage of the words was a SANITARIUM was a mental institution, and a SANITORIUM was a place for people to convalesce, mostly from tuberculosis. The two words were NOT used interchangeably!

Comment: I came to this conclusion: sanitarium is closer to sanitary than is sanitory/sanatory. I'm inclined to consider that a "sanitarium" is a place for chronic care in a "clean" environment, as for tuberculosis, whereas "sanatorium" is closer to the word "insane" and thus a place for long-term care for mental illness.

Comment: Wow, so many differences, and I have yet another. Growing up in the 1960's South, I learned that sanitAriums were for noncontagious, often chronic health conditions. Sometimes they were institutions where rich people went for general health improvements with holistic treatments such as massage, moist hot packs, colon cleansing, wholesome, plant based meals, etc. The best remembered sanitarium of this type was Dr. Kellogg's Sanitarium in Battle Creek, Michigan. Back then sanitOriums were for treating highly contagious such as tuberculosis. Nowadays, they seem to be used interchangeably...if the

Answer (score 4):

According to the  [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/sanatorium-vs-sanatarium/) there is no  difference in meaning. Sanitarium is more common in AmE as shown  [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sanitarium%3Aeng_us_2012%2Csanitarium%3Aeng_gb&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csanitarium%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csanitarium%3Aeng_gb%3B%2Cc0)  while [sanatorium](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sanatorium%3Aeng_us_2012%2Csanatorium%3Aeng_gb&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csanatorium%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csanatorium%3Aeng_gb%3B%2Cc0) appears to be common both in BrE and AmE

> - ***Sanatorium and sanitarium are two words that are very close in spelling and pronunciation.*** We will look at the difference between the words sanatorium and sanitarium and some examples of their use in sentences.
> - A sanatorium is a facility where people with chronic illnesses or a need to convalesce are treated. ***Sanatoriums were first established in the 1800s, mostly to treat tuberculosis***. The purposes of a sanatorium was to first, isolate the afflicted from the healthy population and second, afford the patient a healthy environment in which to heal. Before the advent of antibiotics, tuberculosis was a scourge on the population.
> - A sanitarium is also a facility where people with chronic illnesses or a need to convalesce are treated. The plural forms are sanitariums or sanitaria.
> - ***The terms sanatorium and sanitarium are interchangeable, however, sanitarium is primarily a North American word***. The difference between the words is their origin, though it is not much of a difference. The word sanitorium is derived from the Late Latin word sanitorius, which means health-giving. The word sanitarium is derived from the Latin word sanitas, which means health.

Comment: There's a Metallica song of this name, does it mean that it specifically means a mental hospital? (I always thought this based on the song name, but now it appears it is not true)

Comment: As the answer says, sanitoria/sanitaria were originally established for TB. It is sometimes used as a euphemistic name for mental hospitals, e.g. [in the Simpsons](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Springfield_Sanitarium).

Answer (score 0):

They appear to designate the same thing with **sanatorium** being recorded somewhat earlier and having, to my mind, a better etymological pedigree:

OED

> **sanatorium,** n.
>
> Etymology: < modern Latin sānātōrium, < sānāre to cure, heal:
>
> **1. An establishment for the reception and medical treatment of invalids; in later use chiefly either of convalescent patients, or of
> consumptives undergoing the open-air treatment. Also figurative.**
>
> 1839   London Med. Gaz. 25 406/2   *Dr. Southwood Smith, Dr. Arnott, and some other gentlemen, have it in contemplation to establish, under the name of ‘Sanatorium’, an institution..where patients are provided with board and medical treatment on the payment of a certain sum per week.*

> **sanitarium**, n.
>
> Etymology: quasi-Latin, < sānitās health: see sanitary adj. and -arium suffix.
>
> **= sanatorium n. 1, 2.**
>
> 1851   Lady Bentham in Mechanics' Mag. 55 304   *Sanitariums, wherein the diseased of all ranks might, at moderate cost obtain superior medical advice.*